# GPU not detected after upgrading drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop which contains an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile.

System Info shows that it is detected on the PCI line 1.00.0 and I have no reason to suspect that the problem could be hardware-related.

For a long time I was running NVIDIA driver version 470 and had no issues, until an update to OBS 30.0.2 suggested upgrading new video drivers during troubleshooting.

I found a file for version 450 on an NVIDIA website but it recommended I check my distro's repository for more compatible versions, so I used software-properties-qt or "Software Sources" to check the Additional Drivers tab for the drivers most compatible with my system - I can't remember which version I chose, but I got an error message saying the driver couldn't be installed.

So I figured that I still had 470 installed, and my error in OBS went away - I assumed this was luck, but I noticed that it no longer offered Hardware decoding - and checking System Info showed that Ubuntu no longer recognized the dedicated GPU, instead showing "RENOIR" (a Radeon built into my Ryzen chip.)

So I used software-properties-qt to try to install the drivers again, and was able to complete the process for 535, 545 and others but after rebooting Ubuntu still doesn't recognize the NVIDIA card.

I can't tell why the process isn't working for the recommended driver version 535 (software sources says "This device is using the recommended driver").

I tried reinstalling my current kernel to see if that would help but no results.
Can anybody recommend any troubleshooting steps to get the new driver working?